# Objective-C How do I return a struct datatype?

Tags: objective-c

```
struct Line {

    NSUInteger x1;
    NSUInteger x2;
};

// ...

- (Line)visibleLine;
```

The code above obviously doesn't work because Line is not a valid type. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13):

*Objective-C is a based on C not C++. In `C` we need to use `struct Line`, while in C++ `Line` is fine.*

You can do this as :

```
struct {
    NSUInteger x1;
    NSUInteger x2;
} Line;

// ...

- (struct Line)visibleLine{
    
}
```

---

OR

```
struct Line {
    NSUInteger x1;
    NSUInteger x2;
};
typedef struct Line Line;

// ...

- (Line)visibleLine;
```

> Above is preferred by most C frameworks.

Also,

```
typedef struct {
    NSUInteger x1;
    NSUInteger x2;
} Line;

// ...

- (Line)visibleLine;
```

Answer (score 8):

```
typedef struct {
    NSUInteger x1;
    NSUInteger x2;
} Line;

// ...

- (Line)visibleLine;
```

I originally (before the other answers) suggested the above for a clear reason: this is how Apple does it in its own code. It's not the only way, but it's the standard way Apple does it. It never puts `struct` in the prototype of a method anywhere in its APIs.

Answer (score 5):

In *C*, `struct Line` and `Line` is different. You need to alias `struct Line` to refer it with just `Line`. So,

```
struct Line { /* ... */ };        // Make a struct.

typedef struct Line       Line;   // Make an alias.
```

This also  can be written at once.

```
typedef struct Line { /* ... */ }        Line;
```

*C++* makes the alias automatically, but you should treat *C++* is completely different language with *C*. Don't be confused of their names.

Answer (score 3):

You missed the keyword *struct*.

```
- (struct Line)visibleLine;
```